# Cannot change return type when overriding method, error when using generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I am having trouble overriding a method that returns a generic class that is strongly typed.

This is just setting up for the example below

```
public class Something : ISomething {}
public interface ISomething {}
```

My issue is with the `Clone` method below, only the second one works.

```
public class ClassA : AbstractClass<Something> 
{

    public override ClassA Clone()              // <--- this doesn't work
    {
        return this; // this is just dummy code
    }          

    public override AbstractClass<Something> Clone()    // <-- this works
    {
        return this; // this is just dummy code
    }  

}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : ISomething 
{
    public abstract AbstractClass<T> Clone();          
}
```

I would prefer to have the first `Clone` method, as the name of the class doesn't change. But only the second method compiles. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Side note: your problem have nothing to do with generic - you will get exactly the same result if your `AbstractClass<T>` is some non-generic class `Base`: you still can't change type of result of function when overriding: `public abstract Base Foo()` can to overriden with `public override Derived Foo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another generic parameter for the return type:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<TC, T> where TC: AbstractClass<TC, T> where T : ISomething 
{
    public abstract TC Clone();          
}
```

then change `ClassA` to:

```
public class ClassA : AbstractClass<ClassA, Something>
{
    public override ClassA Clone()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Puzzling downvotes day... Looks like perfectly valid approach to specify exact type one wants to return...

Answer (score 4):

The first override changes the actual signature:

Your method on the base class establishes that it will return an `AbstractClass<T>`.

Since your subclass says that `T` is going to be something, this now implies that the method returns an `AbstractClass<Something>`. While `ClassA` is an `AbstractClass<Something>` that doesn't mean that all `AbstractClass<Something>` are a `ClassA`.

Consider the following example:

```
AbstractClass<Something> myVar = new ClassA(); // works, because ClassA is an AbstractClass<Something>

// Now we hold a reference to an AbstractClass<Something>
myVar.Clone(); // => This should return an AbstractClass<Something> not ClassA
```

Extending the example: consider a ClassB:

```
public class ClassB : AbstractClass<Something> {}
```

Both `ClassA` and `ClassB` are `AbstractClass<Something>`. If we retake the first example:

```
AbstractClass<Something> myVar;
myVar = new ClassA(); 
myVar = new ClassB(); 

// Here you don't know whether it's a ClassA or ClassB, you only know it's an `AbstractClass<Something>`
myVar.Clone();
```

Comment: If that is the case, is there any way to force the clone to always return the type it is and not the base type?

Comment: No, because then that method is specific to each class and thus you can't define it on the parent class.

Comment: +1. There is no way to express "this method returns my run-time type" in C#. Solution suggested by Lee is probably closest you can get, but it makes inheritance almost pointless and still does not force "returns my type" as you need to make sure to pass correct type and only correct for first layer of derived classes.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov doesn't object.GetType() return the run-time type of the object?

Comment: @Moop yes, you can easily get type with `GetType()`... but you can't say `public this.GetType() MyMethod(string  someArg)`

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to change the return type while overriding a method.

You could remove the override from the first implementation, and this will define a new method. But, because you have that abstract Clone method in the base class, you are forced to implement it as well, and you'll end up with 2 methods with the same name, and the same parameters, so the code will not compile.

Do you really need that Clone method in the abstract class ?

I think you should remove the Clone method from the abstract class, and add the Clone method in the derived class (perhaps also implementing ICloneable interface).

Comment: The clone method is just an example. I have some other methods that I would like all derived classes to use, so I would like to define the signature in the abstract class.

Comment: So, you basically want to define a signature in the base class that will return an object of the type of the derived class, without knowing about it at design time. This can't be done in C#. If you really want to go in this direction, you can use the method provided by Lee, but I'd recommend adjusting the design of your solution according to C# rules.